# There Should be exactly one item with Dropdown's Value Error

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-form-builder

I am totally stuck on resolving this error, am new to this platform anyone help me clear this

```
class _EditBasicDetailsScreenState extends State<EditBasicDetailsScreen> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  List _locations = List();
  String _location_id;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _location_id = '';
    _locations = [
      {"location_id": "1", "location_name": "pathirikuppam"},
      {"location_id": "2", "location_name": "koothapakam"},
      {"location_id": "3", "location_name": "thiruvandhipuram"}
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Edit Basic Details"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: ListView(children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.pink, style: BorderStyle.solid, width: 0.80),
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                child: DropdownButton(
                    isExpanded: true,
                    hint: Text('Select Shop Location'),
                    items: _locations.map((dropDowmLocationItem) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                          value: dropDowmLocationItem['location_id'].toString(),
                          child: Text(dropDowmLocationItem['location_name']));
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (String newselectedLocation) {
                      setState(() {
                        _location_id = newselectedLocation;
                      });
                    },
                    value: _location_id)),
          )
        ]),
      ),
     
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

I have attached a screenshot of the error, hope it will tell what's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the initialisation of **_location_id** from your initState() method.

You have initialised the **_location_id** with empty string that's the reason DropDownButton is looking for empty string id in your list items which is not present and the error has been thrown.

**Solution**
Just remove the initialisation of **_location_id** from your initState() method.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in my project and stay for a few days with this problem A solution that helped me was to make a condition in "onChanged", which was as follows: If the controller in the first dropdown is not empty and the second one is also not empty,the second controller is cleared. This condition I put in the onChanged of the two dropdowns.

```
    onChanged: (value) {
 setState(() {
   if (firstController.text.isNotEmpty &&
      secondController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      secondController.clear();
      }
      secondController.text = value.toString();
     });
    },
```